# Docker image in local computer has deleted by Kubernetes garbage collection

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am working on single node kubernetes cluster built with kubeadm. During development, create a new docker image, but the image will be deleted immediately without permission from kubernetes garbage collection. How do I control this?

Environment:

- kubeadm version: v1.17.2
- kubelet version: v1.17.2
- docker version: 19.03.5
- Ubuntu 18.04 desktop
- Linux kernel version: 4.15.0-74-generic

Comment: It will usually only do that if it thinks it is low on disk space. Is it?

Comment: I checked the free space by gparted and found 47.44 Gi. The image I want to generate is about 7Gi, which is enough.

Comment: How do you create the image? Did you verify that indeed the k8s gc is cleaning up the image?

Comment: I created an image with the `docker build` command on master node, and confirmed that the image was deleted immediately with `docker container ls -a`. If I running Docker only, the images have not been deleted. So I guess the reason for the removal was due to the kubernetes garbage collection.

Comment: Try stopping the kubelet to confirm it is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

> I created an image with the `docker build` command on master node, and
>   confirmed that the image was deleted immediately with `docker
>   container ls -a`. If I running Docker only, the images have not been
>   deleted. So I guess the reason for the removal was due to the
>   kubernetes garbage collection. – MASH 3 hours ago

Honestly, I doubt that your recently build docker image could've been deleted by kubernetes garbage collector.

I think you are confusing two concepts: `image` and `stopped container`. If you want to check your local images, you should use `docker image ls` command, not `docker container ls -a`. The last one doesn't say anything about available images and doesn't prove that any image was deleted.

It's totally normal behaviour of **Docker**. Please look at this example from [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/):

We build a new docker image using following commands:

```
# create a directory to work in
mkdir example
cd example

# create an example file
touch somefile.txt

# build an image using the current directory as context, and a Dockerfile passed through stdin
docker build -t myimage:latest -f- . <<EOF
FROM busybox
COPY somefile.txt .
RUN cat /somefile.txt
EOF
```

After successful build:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.103kB
Step 1/3 : FROM busybox
 ---> 020584afccce
Step 2/3 : COPY somefile.txt .
 ---> 216f8119a0e6
Step 3/3 : RUN cat /somefile.txt
 ---> Running in 90cbaa24838c
Removing intermediate container 90cbaa24838c
 ---> b1e6c2284368
Successfully built b1e6c2284368
Successfully tagged myimage:latest
```

we run:

```
$ docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

As you can see there's nothing there and it's totally ok.

But when you run `docker image ls` command instead, you'll see our recently build image:

```
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY                                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
myimage                                   latest              b1e6c2284368        10 seconds ago      1.22MB
```